# How can I use applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to reload data in UIViewController when application become active or become foreground.

I know applicationDidBecomeActive is called in AppDelegate class.
But I have to have a global variable for the UIViewController to reload its data in AppDelegate class like this code:

```
in AppDelegate.m

// global variable
UIViewController *viewController1;
UIViewController *viewController2;

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [viewController1 reloadData];
    [viewController2 reloadData];
}
```

But it is inconvenient especially when I have a lot of UIViewControllers.

Can I use applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController instead of in AppDelegate class?
Or are there better ways than having global variable for UIViewController?

I also need to use the following method from UIViewControllers:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: this code doesn't work because [viewController1 reloadData] is executed when viewController1 is not displayed.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

At the time of reactivation, if you want to carry a particular thing for a view controller, you should register a notification in its `viewDidLoad` method.

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will automatically notify your application and given controller, if they registered for it.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't I have to resister observer in viewWillApper and remove the observer in viewWillDissapear? Because if I don't remove it in viewWillDisappear, callback method is executed after the view is disappeared and this might cause crash.

Comment: Yes..you should do it in that way only.. If you add the observer in viewDidLoad method, you should remove it in dealloc method. If you add it viewWillAppear, you should remove it in viewWillDisAppear method.

Comment: `dealloc` is not necessary on ARC (iOS 7).

Comment: You can safely write dealloc function while working with ARC. You can deallocate references which are created by malloc, new. You can remove observers in dealloc while working with ARC.

Answer (score 59):

Here is an example of registering a notification handler in Swift (adapted from Apurv's answer above):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    // do something
}
```

**Update for `Swift 4.2`:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Application is back in the foreground

    print("active")
}
```

Comment: selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive) is more correct ;)

Comment: @LucasLeon, was just about to post the same thing.  Using strings is basically deprecated in Swift 2.2 and they're thinking of removing that ability entirely in Swift 3.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer, this was written a (relatively) long time ago!

Comment: This code works well in regular ViewController. However when I try doing the same from ViewController which is part of NavigationViewController - then it doesn't work. Selector function isn't called. Is there a diference?

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 3**:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
    object: nil)



func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    // do something
}
```

Note: Don't forget to remove the observer

Comment: As a newcomer to Swift; wouldn't you want to make `applicationDidBecomeActive` above private?

Comment: that's totally up to you, Johnny and to what you need

Comment: OK. I come from a ObjC/C++ etc background where the "default flow" is to hide things away as much as possible, until someone else needs it and only after much begging you *might* open it up. Some people call it low coupling, I guess. Well, it's a longer discussion which probably already exists somewhere else.

Comment: Do you still need to remove the observer? https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/

Comment: better safe than sorry

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `applicationDidBecomeActive` in viewController; it is not a method for that class.

However, you can use `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in AppDelegate to call any methods in your view controller that you feel are important upon launch. Just keep a pointer to your controller so the App Delegate can reach it.

What those methods might be in your view controller is entirely up to you and the details of your program. Maybe it means calling a custom update method in your view controller or whatever else you feel is necessary.

You could also use NSNotificationCenter as outlined here, with many system notifications available for application launch: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

However, relying heavily on NSNotificationCenter is in my opinion a good way for an app to be come disorganized. If you call everything from your main methods in the AppDelegate only, you can always refer to that method to know exactly what your app is doing upon launch. If instead you use NSNotificationCenter, you could have actions spread across many classes/objects and it can be harder to track down what is going on. Since you mentioned multiple controller objects, I think it is more streamlined and organized to call everything from `applicationDidBecomeActive` rather than register each viewcontroller for the same notification.

Answer (score 2):

update for swift 5

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    }
   // remove the observer 
   deinit {

       print("Receiver teardown")

       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

   }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Application is back in the foreground

        print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I remove the observer there ?

Comment: @RaviMan remove the observer  ```deinit {

        print("Receiver teardown")

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }```

Answer (score 0):

just Use NotificationCenter in your UIViewController :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive), 
name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, 
object: nil)
```

Answer (score -8):

Thank you all for answering my question.
But I found easier way to use applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIViewController<MyAppDelegate> *topViewController = (UIViewController<MyAppDelegate> *)navigationController.topViewController;
    if ([topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(MyApplicationDidBecomeActive)]) {
        [topViewController MyApplicationDidBecomeActive];
    }
}
@end

@protocol MyAppDelegate
@optional
-(void)MyApplicationDidBecomeActive;
@end
```

Comment: This design will cause increase code complexity and create tighter coupling which could causing difficulties in debugging issues or making future changes.

Comment: then imagine that you have 20 screens with animations and you want repeat this behaviour for them too....