# How to know when View will become active from background

Tags: ios, swift, methods

Is there no method similar to the `applicationDidBecomeActive`, but that applies to a view controller. I know about `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear`,  which work when you navigate to this view controller, but I need something that is called when the user leaves the app (by pressing home button) and then re-opens the app. I have a global variable that is defined in the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller, but is redefined in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. This means that if the app enters background, and then comes back to the foreground the variable will change. And I need to reset it in something like a `viewDidBecomeActive` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928126/how-can-i-use-applicationdidbecomeactive-in-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply register your view controller to listen to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification.

Add the following in your view controller's viewWillAppear method:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: And the obligatory swift comment.
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector:#selector(Class.method),
                                                         name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
                                                         object: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector:#selector(yourMethod),
        name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil)
```

and at your function

```
@objc func yourMethod() {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector:#selector(refreshWhenAppBecomesActive),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
    object: nil)
```