# When is an app removed from memory

Tags: ios

One of the tabs in my app presents blog posts. I notice that when I move to another tab or leave the app that when I return, new blog posts are not downloading.  The download is kicked off by `viewDidLoad()` in the ViewController.  It's not firing when I return to this view.

Why isn't `viewDidLoad()` firing when I leave the app?  How long does the app remain view loaded in memory?

How should I check for new posts when the user comes back to the app or from another tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `applicationDidBecomeActive` notification to trigger updates or whatever else you want your app to do when it is brought back from the background.

There is a good answer on this here: [How can I use applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928126/how-can-i-use-applicationdidbecomeactive-in-uiviewcontroller)

There is also a good article on Apple's website about handling transitions from various app states here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` may not be the best place to download the updates. If for example you push from ViewController A -> ViewController B, the first view controller (A) isn't unloaded.

You may want to put the code in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

Look at [ViewController LifeCycle](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/ios-essentials-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/) for some reference.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!

Comment: Note that `viewDidAppear` doesn't get called when coming back from the background if that tab is already selected.

Answer (score 1):

ViewDidLoad is only called once when the ViewController is instantiated. In a UITavBarController, the child view controllers are only instantiated once.  As you move from tab to tab, the ViewControllers are kept in memory.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/

If you background the app, then iOS will keep it in memory until it starts to get low, then starts to terminate apps.

Take a look at the delegate for the TabBar

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

This can tell you specifically when the user switches tabs.  But if they flip back and forth, it could needlessly create several API requests.